# Filter only Document Libraries from the listdata.svc Sharepoint Restful Services

Tags: c#, objective-c, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I want to filter only the Document Libraries from the sharepoint 2010 listdata.svc Restful service's response. How can i achieve that?

```
Service URL : http://SITE_URL/_vti_bin/listdata.svc
```

Pls help.